# Spark read table from a specific location

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have saved a dataframe as a table using the following code:

```
yearly_calltype.write.option("path", "/home/user/tables/firstProject").saveAsTable('yearly_calltype_count')
```

But how do I read this table from this location?

When I am trying to do:

```
spark.read.table("/home/user/tables/firstProject/yearly_calltype_count")
```

I am getting this error:

```
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near '/'.(line 1, pos 0)

== SQL ==
/home/user/tables/firstProject/yearly_calltype_count
^^^
```

I believe when we try to read the tables, we cannot specify the location. And spark tries to read the table from default `/home/user/spark-warehouse` location. We can change this location by changing the `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` config. But I do not want to do that. Is there a way I can read this table by specifying the location of the table in the `read.table` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`def table(tableName: String): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` will take only `tableName` not table `path`

You can access table data like below

```
spark
.read
.option("path","/home/user/tables/firstProject")
.table("yearly_calltype_count")
.show(false)
```

OR

```
spark
.read
.table("yearly_calltype_count")
.show(false)
```

OR

```
spark
.read
.parquet("/home/user/tables/firstProject/yearly_calltype_count")
.show(false)
```